# Using the Bubble sort method for an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement the Bubble sort method into an easy coding problem for Ruby, but I'm having some trouble. I understand the idea is to look at the value of the first element and compare it to the value of the second element and then swap them accordingly, but I can't seem to do it in an actual problem. Would anyone be willing to provide a brief example of how this might work in Ruby?

Comment: Do you really need bubble sorting? Is it for didactic or practical purposes? For practical purposes Ruby has many ways of sorting that returns the same results. For example, for ascending sorting of an array you could just do: >> array.sort { |a, b| a <=> b }

Answer (score 14):

Correct implementation of the bubble sort with a while loop

```
def bubble_sort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1 # already sorted
  swapped = true
  while swapped do
    swapped = false
    0.upto(list.size-2) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i+1]
        list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i] # swap values
        swapped = true
      end
    end    
  end

  list
end
```

Comment: Please explain why your solution is "more correct" (not saying it isn't, but that you should always explain why)...

Comment: Yes, but why is the answer incorrect if the block-swapped is set to true... how has reversing the boolean changed the correctness of the return-value. In this case, I'd say "it's correct because bubble sort keeps sorting while there are still swaps being made - as soon as it finds no more swaps, it stops sorting"

Comment: The bubble sort is called bubble sort because in each pass-through, the highest unsorted value “bubbles” up to its correct position. Instead of looping through all the elements inside the while loop, we can make use of it and only use the `upto` loop through the unsorted indices.  since I can't add the answer to this question. please check the gist: https://gist.github.com/shanshaji/5da49d1177cdf1cdc981f3dacc005b56

Answer (score 7):

```
arr = [4,2,5,1]
loop until arr.each_cons(2).with_index.none?{|(x,y),i| arr[i],arr[i+1] = y,x if x > y}
p arr #=> [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Source](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/bubble-sort-ruby)

```
def bubble_sort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1 # already sorted

  loop do
    swapped = false
    0.upto(list.size-2) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i+1]
        list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i] # swap values
        swapped = true
      end
    end
    break unless swapped
  end

  list
end
```

Although I would certainly recommend something with a better run-time than bubblesort :)

Comment: Thanks VanDarg...I'm following Chris Pine's tutorial and he never included anything on the terms loop or break unless. Is there any other way to go about implementing this code say for example with a while loop?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version of the top answer.  It calls size on the array only once instead of every loop.  It doesn't compare elements once they have moved to the end of the array.

And the while loop quits one loop sooner.  You're done once you've gone through the whole array and only did one swap, so no need to do another with 0 swaps.

```
def bubble_sort(list)
  iterations = list.size - 2

  return list unless iterations > 0 # already sorted

  swaps = 2

  while swaps > 1 do
    swaps = 0

    0.upto(iterations) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i + 1]
        list[i], list[i + 1] = list[i + 1], list[i] # swap values
        swaps += 1
      end
    end

    iterations -= 1
  end

  list
end
```

Running this test takes 25% less time.

```
that_array = this_array = [22,66,4,44,5,7,392,22,8,77,33,118,99,6,1,62,29,14,139,2]
49.times {|variable| that_array = that_array + this_array}
bubble_sort that_array
```

Answer (score 1):

Just re-writing @VanDarg's code to use a while loop
(note: code not tested... run at your own peril)

```
def bubble_sort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1 # already sorted

  swapped = true
  while swapped
    swapped = false # maybe this time, we won't find a swap
    0.upto(list.size-2) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i+1]
        list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i] # swap values
        swapped = true # found a swap... keep going
      end
    end
  end

  list
end
```

**Edit:** updated swapped-values because bubble sort keeps sorting while there are still swaps being made - as soon as it finds no more swaps, it stops sorting. Note, this does *not* follow @Doug's code, but does conform with @cLuv's fix

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubble_sort array 
  array.each do
    swap_count = 0
    array.each_with_index do |a, index|
      break if index == (array.length - 1)
      if a > array[index+1]
        array[index],array[index+1] = array[index +1], array[index]
        swap_count += 1
      end
    end
    break if swap_count == 0 # this means it's ordered
  end
  array
end
```

Comment: Try providing more detail in your answer.

Comment: No reason to use each_with_index here, ultimately.  You're only looking for a counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def bubbleSort(list)
  sorted = false
  until sorted
    sorted = true
    for i in 0..(list.length - 2)
      if list[i] > list[i + 1]
        sorted = false
        list[i], list[i + 1] = list[i + 1], list[i]
      end
    end
  end
  return list
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward:

```
def bubble_sort(n)
  return n if n.length <= 1

  0.upto(n.length - 1) do |t|
    0.upto(n.length - 2 - t) do |i|
      if n[i] > n[i + 1]
        n[i], n[i + 1] = n[i + 1], n[i]
      end
    end
  end

  n
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.  I like using the (arr.length-1).  For loops you can also use such iterations such as until, while, for, upto, loop do, etc.  Fun to try different things to see how it functions.

```
def bubble_sort(arr)  #10/17/13 took me 8mins to write it

return arr if arr.length <= 1

sorted = true

    while sorted
     sorted = false
     (arr.length-1).times do |i|
        if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
          arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
          sorted = true
        end
       end
     end
    arr
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use this funny swapping line (IMO):

```
    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
```

here's my take:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  temp = 0

  arr.each do |i|
    i = 0
    j = 1
    while (j < arr.length)
      if arr[i] > arr[j]
        temp = arr[i] 
        arr[i] = arr[j]
        arr[j] = temp 
        p arr
      end
    i+=1
    j+=1
    end
  end  
 arr
end
```

Comment: You could use PHP too

Answer (score 0):

Old school

```
def bubble_sort(random_numbers)
for i in 0..random_numbers.size 
  for j in i+1..random_numbers.size-1    
    random_numbers[i], random_numbers[j] = random_numbers[j], random_numbers[i] if(random_numbers[i] > random_numbers[j])
  end
end
random_numbers
end
```

Comment: looks more like python than ruby

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my take using the operator XOR:**

```
def bubble(arr)
     n = arr.size - 1
     k = 1
     loop do
          swapped = false
          0.upto(n-k) do |i|
              if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
                 xor = arr[i]^arr[i+1]
                 arr[i] = xor^arr[i]
                 arr[i+1] = xor^arr[i+1]
                 swapped = true  
              end 
          end 
          break unless swapped
          k +=1 
     end
   return arr
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
a = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
n = a.length

for j in 0..n-1
    for i in 0..n - 2 - j
           if a[i]>a[i+1]
                tmp = a[i]
                a[i] = a[i+1]
                a[i+1] = tmp
          end
     end
end

puts a.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, slightly different naming.

```
def bubble_sort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1
  not_sorted = true

  while not_sorted
    not_sorted = false

    0.upto(list.size - 2) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i + 1]
        list[i], list[i + 1] = list[i + 1], list[i]
        not_sorted = true
      end
    end
  end
  list
end
```