# Where is the bug in my bubble sort code?

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort

I see that there are better ruby bubble sort codes already posted in places such as here:
[Using the Bubble sort method for an array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091434/using-the-bubble-sort-method-for-an-array-in-ruby)
But I am having trouble debugging my current code and would appreciate some help with figuring out why my code does not work.  Thanks.

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    original = arr
    x = 0
    while x < arr.count - 1
        if arr[x] < arr[x + 1]
            y = arr[x + 1]
            arr[x + 1] = arr[x]
            arr[x] = y
        end
        x += 1
    end
    if original == arr
        return arr
    else
        return bubble_sort(arr)
    end 
end
```

Comment: define "does not work"

Comment: `original = arr` does not do what you think it does. You are modifying `original` too. Try `... = arr.dup`.

Comment: While bubble sort is not very efficient anyway, this is about the worst variant of it I could imagine.

Comment: @undur_gongor: which means that the OP has a lot of potential :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four issues :

1. `bubble_sort[arr]` does not work - you should call `bubble_sort(arr)`
2. `original == arr` - will always be true, since you assigned it to `arr` before - you should have assigned it using `dup` - `original = arr.dup`
3. `arr[x] < arr [x+1]` will create an array sorted in reverse order...
4. you should change the local copy rather than the one you got as parameters - `result = arr.dup` rather than `original = arr.dup`

The code after the above fixes:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  result = arr.dup
  x = 0
  while x < result.count - 1
    if result[x] > result[x + 1]
      y = result[x + 1]
      result[x + 1] = result[x]
      result[x] = y
    end
    x += 1
  end
  if arr == result
    return result
  else
    return bubble_sort(result)
  end 
end

bubble_sort([1,3,5,2,4])
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Might be slightly cleaner to use `result.count.times do |x|` instead of `while ...` ? That way you don't need to manually initialize or increment the index.

Comment: There are ten different ways to make this code cleaner - my aim was to make it work. After it works, I would suggest that the OP will take it over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for some serious review.

Answer (score 3):

One of the problems is this:

```
original = arr
```

You expect `original` to a copy of `arr` in its current state, right? Well, no. They will point to the same array. That's why your function will never recurse here:

```
if original == arr
    return arr
else
    return bubble_sort[arr]
end
```

To copy the array, use `dup`

```
original = arr.dup
```