# Bubble Sort method

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort

I am just learning ruby and KevinC's response [(in this link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091434/using-the-bubble-sort-method-for-an-array-in-ruby/27832801#27832801) makes sense to me with one exception. I don't understand why the code is encompassed in the  arr.each do |i|    #while... end That part seems redundant to me as the 'while' loop is already hitting each of the positions? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop finds a bubble and carries it up; if it finds another, lighter bubble, it switches them around and carries the lighter one. So you need several passes through the array to find all the bubbles and carry them to the correct place, since you can't float several bubbles at the same time.

EDIT:

The `each` is really misused in KevinC's code, since it is not used for its normal purpose: yielding *elements* of the collection. Instead of `arr.each`, it would be better to use `arr.size.times` - as it would be more informative to the reader. Redefining the `i` within the block is adding insult to injury. While none of this will cause the code to be *wrong* as such, it is misleading.

The other problem with the code is the fact that it does not provide the early termination condition (`swapped` in most other answers on that question). In theory, bubble sort could find the array sorted in the first pass; the other `size - 1` steps are unnecesary. KevinC's code would still dry-hump the already sorted array, never realising it is done.

As for rewrite into block-less code, it is certainly possible, but you need to understand that blocks syntax is very idiomatic in Ruby, and non-block loops are almost unheard of in Ruby world. While Ruby has `for`, it is pretty much *never* used in Ruby. But...

```
arr.each do |i|
  ...
end
```

is equivalent to

```
for i in arr
  ...
end
```

which is, again, at least for the array case, equivalent to

```
index = 0
while index < arr.size
  i = arr[index]
  ...
  index += 1
end
```

Comment: I don't quite understand blocks yet... is it possible to re-write kevinC's code without using the .each method?